# Slow settlement for safe wallet in Plutus

Tags: plutus, wallet

The problem I'm trying to solve -- I want to move my crypto off exchange, but I'm afraid I will be hacked or lose my keys.

Solution -- wallet that takes 1 day to settle every outgoing transaction. During that one day, it scans the blockchain for my public key to see if I cancelled the transaction. (You could set up notifications for every withdrawal, so you know if a hacker is trying to withdraw).

After 3 cancelled transactions or 1 year with no transactions (keys are lost), the wallet sends all its coins to another address (possibly in some custodial account, arbitration code, or a friend's account).

Usage -- keep 90% of money in safe wallet, and 10% in hot wallet to do stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Your crypto is actually not stored in your wallet. It is stored on the blockchain. Having a wallet that is slow to figure out the state of the blockchain doesn't make your wallet any safer. Your crypto transactions move at the speed of the blockchain whether you want them to or not.

The way to ensure you're not hacked or lose your keys/mnemonics is to properly back them up and also utilize hardware wallets.

There's no possibility of slowing down the blockchain for individual users.